# height of child divs when parent div height is 100%

Tags: html, css

I have one containing div with two child divs.

All divs are the same width and children divs appear on top of each other; containing div's height is 100% and the second child div's height is fixed at 25px.

Without javascript, how do I make it so that the first child div's height is the difference between the container div's height (based on the 100%) and the second child div (25px) ?

Comment: Applying 100% height to the first child didn't work?

Comment: simple answer: you can't. it's not possible to mix % and px in css..

Comment: Not possible. Why no JavaScript?

Comment: @micha - The requirement says "without javascript".

Comment: ok not possible is maybe too much: http://jsfiddle.net/x8b2P/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per i understand your question may be you can use `display:table` property. Like this:

```
.parent{
    display:table;
    height:300px;
    width:100%
}
.parent div{
    display:table-row;
    width:100%;

}
.child{
    background:green;
}
.child2{
    background:red;
    height:25px;
}
```

### http://jsfiddle.net/WBh9W/4/

`display:table` property is not work in IE7 & below.